# Excluding rows depending upon other rows in table

Tags: sql

I have a table `FooBaz` with rows like this (the primary-key is a composite of `FooId` and `baz`):

```
 FooId, Baz, DateTime
    1,   2, '2014-05-27 00:01'
    2,   2, '2014-05-27 00:01'
    3,   2, '2014-05-27 00:01'
    1,   3, '2014-05-26 00:01'
    2,   4, '2014-05-27 00:01'
    3,   5, '2014-05-28 00:01'
```

I have a query which finds all of the rows where `Baz == 2` (amongst other things, not included in this StackOverflow post for brevity), which returns this:

```
FooId, Bar, DateTime
    1,   2, '2014-05-27 00:01'
    2,   2, '2014-05-27 00:01'
    3,   2, '2014-05-27 00:01'
```

However, I want to exclude rows where the same `FooId` appears with a later `DateTime` when associated with another `Baz` (in this case, the last row where `FooId == 3` and `Baz == 5` should be excluded because its `DateTime` is greater than `2014-05-27 00:01`).

i.e. so the final result set should be this:

```
 FooId, Baz, DateTime
     1,   2, '2014-05-27 00:01'
     2,   2, '2014-05-27 00:01'
```

Please don't tell me the solution involves a cross-join, I don't want to think :)

Answer (score 1):

**NOT EXISTS**

```
SELECT * FROM FooBaz t1
WHERE Baz = 2
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM FooBaz t2
    WHERE t2.FooId = t1.FooId
    AND t2.DateTime < t1.DateTime
    AND t2.Baz <> t1.Baz
)
```

**LEFT JOIN**

```
SELECT t1.FooId, t1.Baz, t1.DateTime 
FROM FooBaz t1
LEFT JOIN FooBaz t2 ON t2.FooId = t1.FooId
    AND t2.DateTime < t1.DateTime
    AND t2.Baz <> t1.Baz
WHERE t1.Baz = 2 
AND t2.FooId IS NULL
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! I forgot about `EXISTS`. I need to work this into a `PARTITION` though. I'm wondering how I can do that.

Comment: Not sure how to do it using `PARTITION`. You could do a `LEFT JOIN` using the same conditions as the `EXISTS` and check for NULL but I think that would be slower